Can Rental Income Be Garnished?
A creditor can request garnishment of a debtor's wages to help repay a debt. In my understanding, part of the practical advantage of garnishing wages is that it enlists a third party (the debtor's employer) to collect a debt when the debtor is unwilling to pay.
What if the debtor is a landlord who collects most of their income through rent payments: could a court direct the tenant to "garnish" rent payments by paying the creditor instead of their landlord?
Practical Scenario
Here's a scenario where this might be a practical route: Assume that the debt at issue is an assessment levied by a condo association against Alex (a single condo owner) to pay for building repairs. Alex rents his condo to Beth. If the association were to sue Alex, the court case may drag on without them seeing any money for a long time. But Beth might be quite willing to cooperate and shift her rent payments to the association immediately, particularly if the repairs impact her directly.
My Question:

Is this legal? Is there any precedent for such a court order?
In the hypothetical scenario described, is this approach actually practical, vis-a-vis other options?

If important, assume the jurisdiction is the USA, state of Illinois.

Wouldn't the condo association have to sue Alex, and win, before a court would issue such an order?

This makes no sense. Unless there is a court or some kind of agreement to which Alex is a part, if Beth decides to pay the condo association it is her problem. Beth is not free to choose who she pays to. Beth still has to pay the agreed rent to the landlord.

In my understanding the garnishing of wages could only happen after a court case established the unwillingsness to pay. Whether a rental income could be garnished in such a situation is still an interesting question though.

Beth can't do this on her own. If a court orders the rent garnished (assuming this is a thing), then she would be obliged to pay the condo association instead of Alex, just as an employer is obliged to redirect wages that are garnished.

Yes, I assume that to issue an order, the court would have to find that Alex was unwilling to pay. I was interested whether this is a measure the court would consider to enforce its decision. Obviously Beth cannot do this by herself as a vigilante.

Yes
A garnishee order can be sought on any debtor of the person who owes the judgement debt. This would include their tenants if they own rental property. Or their bank.
